# Stop WPS Office from recovering deleted files

Tags: applications

Occasionally, I'd see a message that says WPS Office has recovered a deleted file or something like that. I suspect often times, WPS just does it without even letting me know it has recovered files. I really don't like it doing things for me without my consent. How do I stop WPS Office from recovering files? I have gone through the settings in WPS Office and found nothing of the sort.

This is on a Huawei GR5 2017.

Comment: Check whether backup to WPS cloud is switched on.

Comment: Cloud is not turned on. It's puzzling where WPS backs up the files to.

Answer (score 1):

WPS keeps discarded and deleted files in case you need to save or recover them in the future. You are correct that there is no setting related to recovered/retrieved files. However if you are the "Recents" tab, click on the 3-dot then "Retrieved documents", you will be able to see them.

The retrieved files can be found in `/path_Internal_Or_SdCard/Android/data/cn.wps.moffice_eng/.cache/KingsoftOffice/file/.recovery` folder. Inside the folder, filenames are in base64 except for `mapping.info` file which contains their status (real filenames, whether a file was not saved or deleted, etc).

Comment: Thanks. I don't want WPS to save or recover files. I use WPS only to read files, not editing. Somehow WPS saves copies of the files I read. The copies are exact duplicates of the original files. That's a waste of disk space.  I delete them but WPS recovers them. So, I wonder if there is a way to stop WPS from recovering files.

Comment: @joehua There is no setting unfortunately, You will have to check the retrieve files (when you finished reading) via 3-dot > "Retrieved documents" or going through the folders mentioned in the answer to delete/remove them.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Maybe I should find another reader.